# Is Python's speed enough or should I use Pyrex?

Tags: python, django, pyrex

info:
I'm using Django.
question:
Is Python's speed enough for providing a **low latency** web service or should I translate my functions to C using Pyrex?

Comment: Pretty hard to answer without knowing how fast is fast enough.  Additionally, I don't think majority of the latency in a web service is usually due to code execution..

Comment: Two points: **(1)** The significant delays would come from DB queries **(2)** You would want PyPy, a [Python compiler](http://speed.pypy.org/) to [speed up](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndPyPy) CPU-intensive tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of people *do* use Python to implement web services (hence Django existing at all), and find it low enough latency for their purposes. So in one sense, the answer is a trivial "yes".

To answer properly requires lots more information and *study*, and isn't really appropriate for SO's format. For starters, you need to know how fast is "fast enough" (and even for that, you need to figure out how much latency there's going to be due to other factors, such as network latency). It also obviously depends on what your implementation actually is; if all your program does is fetch records from a database, then the code execution will probably be dwarfed by database and network latency whether you use pure Python or C. OTOH, if you're solving arbitrarily large NP-hard computational problems, Python might be starting to look a little less attractive. OTOOH, if you're solving really tricky to implement computational problems, Python will probably dramatically decrease the time it takes you to have your service at all, and a slow service is usually preferable to a non-existent one.

With no actual concrete knowledge, the existence of other web services written in Python makes me intuit that you'll probably be fine in Python, and you should just go and do it and then see if there are any performance bottlenecks that would benefit from being Pyrexed. There's the usual "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" line to consider; before you've even written any code is WAY too early to be thinking about optimisation. As long as it's not blindingly obvious that your approach can never be fast enough, go with the simplest implementation and speed it up later.

Answer (score 4):

Really, the only way you can know (IMO) is to *try it* and see. If and when you start experiencing performance issues, then it is time to profile, and see if it is code execution, or something *else* causing the delays.

Personally, I think you will have no problems. But then again, it depends on what exactly your web service is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about translating the code you haven't even written yet to C you might as well write your web service in C from the start. That'll get you the lowest latency possible.

Comment: While we are on that: http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/03/replacing-small-c-programs-with-haskell/ Saw this today

Comment: Haskell's too different to learn without a clear need for it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it it, you don't want to use Pyrex anyway. You want to use [Cython](http://cython.org/) as it's a more advanced version of the same thing.

Secondly, surely the beauty of using something like Cython is that you can just write your code in Python, and if it's not fast enough, the changes aren't huge to get the speedups you need.

Optimise when you know there's a problem.